# Create an instance of class by Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, this, instance, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create this C# class by using System.Reflection.Emit.

```cs
private class MyTestData : IMyClonable
{
    private int _testValue = 0;
    public int testValue
    {
        get { return _testValue; }
        set { _testValue = value; }
    }

    public IMyClonable Clone()
    {
        MyTestData clone = new MyTestData();
        clone._testValue = _testValue;
        return clone ;
    }
}
```

This class must be created from this interface:

```cs
public interface IMyTestData : IMyClonable
{
    int testValue { get; set; }
}
```

I already made the code that generate properties and this work's fine. But I stuck when I'm trying to create method Clone(). I don't know how to create an instance of this class itself and save it in a local variable. 
Here is the code to generate method Clone():

```cs
private static void MakeCloneMethod(Type componentType, TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
{
    ConstructorBuilder ctor = 
        typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

    MethodInfo cloneMethod = typeof(IMyClonable).GetMethod("Clone");
    MethodAttributes methodIlAttributes = 
        (cloneMethod.Attributes & ~MethodAttributes.Abstract) | MethodAttributes.Final;

    MethodBuilder cloneMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "Clone", methodIlAttributes, typeof(IMyClonable), new Type[] { });
    ILGenerator ilgen = cloneMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

    LocalBuilder returnValue = ilgen.DeclareLocal(typeBuilder.AsType());

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, returnValue);

    CloneProperties(componentType, ilgen);

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(cloneMthdBldr, cloneMethod);
}

private static void CloneProperties(Type componentType, ILGenerator ilgen)
{
    PropertyInfo[] allProperties = GetPublicProperties(componentType);
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in allProperties)
    {
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, builders[propInfo]);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, builders[propInfo]);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    }
}
```

I get the System.InvalidProgramException when I try to call Clone() method. Even if I comment call of method CloneProperties(). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to save your assembly to disk and the run peverify on it?

Comment: to svick: I found my mistakes thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Here is working code:

```cs
private static void MakeCloneMethod(Type componentType, TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
{
    Type thisType = typeBuilder.AsType();
    Type itype = typeof(IMyClonable);
    MethodInfo cloneMthd = itype.GetMethod("Clone");

    MethodBuilder cloneMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        cloneMthd.Name, cloneMthd.Attributes & ~MethodAttributes.Abstract, 
        itype, new Type[] {});
    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(cloneMthdBldr, cloneMthd);

    ILGenerator gen = cloneMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

    LocalBuilder returnValue = gen.DeclareLocal(thisType);

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public));
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, returnValue);

    PropertyInfo[] allProperties = GetPublicProperties(componentType);
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in allProperties)
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, returnValue);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, builders[propInfo]);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, builders[propInfo]);
    }

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, returnValue);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

Thanks to [Svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick)!